# CSS3 animations AND hover transitions

Tags: css, animation, transition

I have no trouble performing CSS3 transitions and animations, but I'm finding trouble combining them without some glitches.

I have a list of links. When the user hovers over one, it should glow (using text-shadow), but sort of slowly pulse in and out. But hovering and leaving the link should give a slight transition in and out of the glow. I can't seem to get the animation to end smoothly. Since the animation starts with a "glow in", that's fine, but the moment the user leaves the link, it reverts to it's ON state, and then transitions to OFF. This looks fine if the animation happens to be full on at the time of leaving, but if the glow is low, it will first blink full on and then go out.

I'm aware of the need to use different vendor prefixes, for the example I'll just use the webkit versions:

```
li {
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,0);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

li:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,1);
  -webkit-animation: blink 0.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink { 
    0% { text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,0) }
    100% { text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,1) }
}
```

FYI, notice that I'm using just 0% and 100%, but with the "alternate" direction parameter set, which produces a reverse-loop (same as if I set a 0% 50% and 100%). I'm sure this is not the cause of the problem.

It's just "shutting down" the animation immediately when the link is left, with no transition out, even though I have the transition time set.

Comment: can you put your code into a jsfiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use animation just use hover and transition

```css
body{
  background:#0077aa;
  }
li {
  font-size:3em;
  -webkit-text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,0);
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,0);
  transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
}

li:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,1);
  -webkit-text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
  </ul>
```